# IBM DB2 integration with Laravel 8 using cooperl/laravel-db2 packa

Tags: laravel, db2

I have Laravel 8 project with (PHP version 7.4). I have also setup database credentials in database.php file. When i tried to fetch record from database in controller, then this error came.

> ErrorException Undefined index: database

Here is db credentials are like this

```
'db2' => [
            'driver' => 'db2_ibmi_ibm',
            'driverName' => '{IBM i Access ODBC Driver}',
            'host' => '',
            'username' => '',
            'password' => '',
            'database' => '',
            'prefix' => '',
            'schema' => 'default schema',
            'port' => 80000,
            'date_format' => 'Y-m-d H:i:s',
            // or 'Y-m-d H:i:s.u' / 'Y-m-d-H.i.s.u'...
            'odbc_keywords' => [
                'SIGNON' => 3,
                'SSL' => 0,
                'CommitMode' => 2,
                'ConnectionType' => 0,
                'DefaultLibraries' => '',
                'Naming' => 0,
                'UNICODESQL' => 0,
                'DateFormat' => 5,
                'DateSeperator' => 0,
                'Decimal' => 0,
                'TimeFormat' => 0,
                'TimeSeparator' => 0,
                'TimestampFormat' => 0,
                'ConvertDateTimeToChar' => 0,
                'BLOCKFETCH' => 1,
                'BlockSizeKB' => 32,
                'AllowDataCompression' => 1,
                'CONCURRENCY' => 0,
                'LAZYCLOSE' => 0,
                'MaxFieldLength' => 15360,
                'PREFETCH' => 0,
                'QUERYTIMEOUT' => 1,
                'DefaultPkgLibrary' => 'QGPL',
                'DefaultPackage' => 'A /DEFAULT(IBM),2,0,1,0',
                'ExtendedDynamic' => 0,
                'QAQQINILibrary' => '',
                'SQDIAGCODE' => '',
                'LANGUAGEID' => 'ENU',
                'SORTTABLE' => '',
                'SortSequence' => 0,
                'SORTWEIGHT' => 0,
                'AllowUnsupportedChar' => 0,
                'CCSID' => 819,
                'GRAPHIC' => 0,
                'ForceTranslation' => 0,
                'ALLOWPROCCALLS' => 0,
                'DB2SQLSTATES' => 0,
                'DEBUG' => 0,
                'TRUEAUTOCOMMIT' => 0,
                'CATALOGOPTIONS' => 3,
                'LibraryView' => 0,
                'ODBCRemarks' => 0,
                'SEARCHPATTERN' => 1,
                'TranslationDLL' => '',
                'TranslationOption' => 0,
                'MAXTRACESIZE' => 0,
                'MultipleTraceFiles' => 1,
                'TRACE' => 0,
                'TRACEFILENAME' => '',
                'ExtendedColInfo' => 0,
            ],
            'options' => [
                PDO::ATTR_CASE => PDO::CASE_LOWER,
                PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => false
            ]
            // + (defined('PDO::I5_ATTR_DBC_SYS_NAMING') ? [PDO::I5_ATTI5_ATTR_DBC_SYS_NAMINGR_COMMIT => false] : [])
            // + (defined('PDO::I5_ATTR_COMMIT') ? [PDO::I5_ATTR_COMMIT => PDO::I5_TXN_NO_COMMIT] : [])
            // + (defined('PDO::I5_ATTR_JOB_SORT') ? [PDO::I5_ATTR_JOB_SORT => false] : [])
            // + (defined('PDO::I5_ATTR_DBC_LIBL') ? [PDO::I5_ATTR_DBC_LIBL => ''] : [])
            // + (defined('PDO::I5_ATTR_DBC_CURLIB') ? [PDO::I5_ATTR_DBC_CURLIB => ''] : [])
        ],
```

> In controller, I have done like this

```
$products = LeiobjProduktP::limit(1)->get(); 
return response()->json(['products' => $products]);
```

On hosting server, Db2 can not access using odbc driver.

I have done simple PHP script to make connection with db. it worked successfully. Here is script

```
$host = 'dummy'; // The IP address or hostname of your IBM i server 
$database = 'dummy'; // The name of your database on the IBM i system 
$username = 'test'; // Your database username 
$password = 'test'; // Your database password // Construct the ODBC connection string 
$port = 80000; 
$dsn = "DRIVER={IBM i Access ODBC Driver};DATABASE=$database;SYSTEM=$host;Port=$port;PROTOCOL=TCPIP";

$connection = db2_connect($dsn, $username, $password); // Check if the connection was successful 
if ($connection) { 
    echo "Connected to the IBM i database."; // Perform database operations here 
    db2_close($connection); // Close the database connection when done 
} else { 
    echo "Failed to connect to the IBM i database."; 
}
```

server 'ibm_db2' extension enabled
[image]

Please guide regarding this.

I have setup the package successfully and tried to access the database.

Comment: and where is that error coming from ....

Comment: when i call 
$products = LeiobjProduktP::limit(1)->get(); 
return response()->json(['products' => $products]);

it is hosted on IBM cloud.

Comment: right ...where does it say the error is coming from (it has to be from some code that is trying to access that index)